# how safe is to pass the 'user' to javascript Ajax in laravel?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, laravel, security

I already asked about this situation but when you pass the data directly to the view like this:
you get the user with `$user = Auth::user();` and then send it to the view with `return view ('somepage')->with('user',$user);` the browser will get all user data in the view (uername, password, user_id etc..).
And found out it should be safe. Now I am thinking what if you instead are passing it to a script that is in charge of updating the view?
Like this:

```
return Response()->json($user);
```

You are firing a json in the wild that gets into the script as `data`, so can a third party have access to that json data too?

Comment: It's pretty simple: what exactly is the body of the HTTP response? Go ahead, open your browser's inspector tools and look at the actual network request and response. Is there any sensitive data in there? Then you're publicly exposing sensitive data and should stop doing that.

Answer (score 0):

No, you DO NOT want to pass any sensitive data to a script or through JSON. Both of these resources would be viewable from the client side.

You can however, remove the sensitive data from your object before serializing it to JSON and passing to the browser.

In your Eloquent models, add a `$hidden` property - this property is an array of attributes that will be removed when serializing the model to JSON.

So, your `User` model will look like:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['password'];
}
```

Then, the `password` will be removed and not accessible from the client.

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json